# overloading operator=, troublesome destructor in a class C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a one-directional list. Everything works perfectly fine until the command m3=m1+m2 is doubled in the main function. When I was debugging I noticed that in the overloaded = operator, after the destruction happens, the values assigned to the o1 object disappear. No idea if there is something wrong with destructor, or the operator =.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    class Element;

    template <class T>
    class List{
        friend class Element<T>;
        Element<T> *head;
    public:
        List(){
            cout<<"konstruktor"<<endl;
            head=NULL;
        }
        ~List() {
            Element<T> *tmp = head;
            cout << "destruktor" << endl;
            while (tmp) {
                //tmp = tmp->next;
                delete head;
                head = tmp;
            }
        }
        friend istream &operator>>(istream &p, List<T> &o1){
            Element<T>* new_ele;
            Element<T>* it;
            it=o1.head;
            new_ele=new Element<T>;
            p>>new_ele->value;
            new_ele->next=NULL;
            if (o1.head==NULL){
                o1.head=new_ele;
            }
            else{
                while (it->next!=NULL){
                    it=it->next;
                }
                it->next=new_ele;
            }
            return p;
        }
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, List<T> &o1){
            Element<T>* it;
            it=o1.head;
            while(it){
                s<<it->value<<" ";
                it=it->next;
            }
            return s;
        }
        List <T> &operator=(const List<T> &o1){
            if (this==&o1){
                return *this;
            }
            Element<T> *it1, *it2, *itc;
            this->~List();//this is the where everything goes haywire
            itc=head;
            it1=o1.head;
            while(it1){
                itc=new Element<T>;
                if (!head) head=it1;
                itc->next=NULL;
                itc->value=it1->value;
                it1=it1->next;
                itc=itc->next;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        List<T> &operator+(List<T> &o1){
            if(o1.head==NULL){
                return *this;
            }else if(head==NULL){
                return o1;
            }
            static List<T> res=*this;
            Element<T> *it;
            it=res.head;
            while(it->next) {
                it = it->next;
            }
            Element <T> *o1_it=o1.head;
            while(o1_it){
                Element<T> *copy;
                copy=new Element<T>;
                copy->next=NULL;
                copy->value=o1_it->value;
                it->next=copy;
                it=it->next;
                o1_it=o1_it->next;
            }
            return res;
        }

        int length_list(){
            Element<T> *it;
            int count_elements=0;
            it=head;
            while(it->next){
                count_elements++;
                it=it->next;
            }
            return count_elements;
        }

        void bubblesort_List(){
            Element<T> *it;
            for(int i=0; this->length_list() > i;i++){
                it = head;
                while (it->next) {
                    if (it->next->value < it->value) {
                        T tmp = it->value;
                        it->value = it->next->value;
                        it->next->value = tmp;
                    }
                    it = it->next;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    template <class T>
    class Element{
        friend class List<T>;
        friend istream &operator>>(istream &p, List<T> &o1);
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, List<T> &o1);

        Element<T> *next;
        T value;
    public:
        Element(){
            next=NULL;
        }
    };
    int main(){

        List<int> m1, m2, m3;

        cin>>m1>>m1>>m1;
        cin>>m2;
        m3=m1+m2;
        m3=m1+m2;
        cout<<m3<<endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Never call destructor explicitly. There are rare exceptions but it is very unlikely you meet them in your life.

Answer (score 0):

Two main issues

- call delete to invoke destructor, never explicitly call ~List. Just call it free_list or something and call it on head
- your destructor is broken, it's not freeing memory up correctly

you want :

```
void free_list (Element<T> * head) {
   Element<T> *tmp = head;
   while (tmp != null) {
     head = tmp.next;
     delete tmp;
     tmp = head;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this->~List();
```

this destroys the object.  It doesn't just run the destructor.

After an object is destroyed, its storage remains, but *there is no object there*.  Interacting with the storage as if there was an object there is undefined behavior.

Move the body of the destructor to a helper function called `clear()`:

Fix it:

```
    clear() {
        std::cout << "clear" << std::endl;
        while (head) {
          Element<T>* tmp = head;
          head=head->next;
          delete tmp;
        }
    }
```

and make your `~List()` be simply `clear()`.

Next, lets fix your `operator=`.

```
    List& operator=(List&&o) {
      if (this==&o)
        return *this;
      clear();
      head = o.head;
      o.head = nullptr;
      return *this
    }
    List& operator=(const List &o) {
      if (this== &o)
        return;
      *this = List(o); // call operator=(List&&) using a copy of o
      return *this;
    }
    List(List&& o):
      head(o.head)
    {
      o.head = nullptr;
    }
    List():head(nullptr) {}
    // all of the work goes on here:
    List(List const& o):List()
    {
      Element<T>* src = o.head;
      Element<T>** dest = &head;
      while(src) {
        *dest = new Element<T>;
        (*dest)->value = src->value;
        (*dest)->next = nullptr;
        src = src->next;
        dest = &((*dest)->next);
      }
    }
```

I have chained everything to work off simpler functions.

`=(&&)` and `(&&)` (move-assign and move-construct) copies `head` and clears the source.  This is a small amount of duplicate code.

`=(const&)` (copy-assign) uses `=(&&)` (move-assign) and `(const&)` (copy-construct).  The business of copying nodes is hard; do it in one situation.  Copying into an empty instance is easier than into one that already exists.

`(const&)` is the only one that does the work.  Here I keep a pointer-to-the-tail-pointer of my linked list, and a pointer-to-the-next-element-to-add.

Then I splice a copy of the next element in, and update my tail and next element pointers.